# How to use browserify while retaining native async/await

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browserify

I am using npm browserify to combine typescript code and google protobuf lib to a single js. This is required as google protobuf has no proper support for browser ES6-style imports (see [Google Protobuf JS](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/js))

```
browserify --standalone -o {file} {input files}
```

The async/await functions are transformed with __awaiter functions but I want to retain (es8) them from any transformation instead use native async/await

I tried searching for any params to be passed to browserify command which can exclude async/await transformation

Sample code:

typescript code:

```
public async Start (milliseconds: number):
Promise<number>
{
  await this.Clear();
  return calc(milliseconds);
}
```

current browserify output:

```
 Start(milliseconds = null) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            yield this.Clear();
            return calc(milliseconds);
        });
 }
```

**Required output (async / await retained):**

```
async Start(milliseconds = null) {
        await this.Clear();
        return calc(milliseconds);
}
```

typescript compiled code is correct with es8 config but when passed to browserify, its adding these extra functions which are not needed.
Any help in this regard is appreciated

Comment: You'll want to choose ES8 (ES2017) as the target. ES7 didn't have `async function`s.

Comment: Bergi: Thank you, agreed and changed but still having issues with browserify

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript and browserify, you may want to use [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify) as plugin to browserify when bundling your code. You can do that like this on the command line:

```
 browserify js/main.ts -p [ tsify -p tsconfig.json ] -o output/main.js
```

Compiled and bundled code in the browser (main.js) using target **ES2018** in my tsconfig.json:

```
 async logIn(password) {
    const req = {
        password: password
    };
    const response = await window.fetch(`/something/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        // headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(req)
    });
    const resp = await response.json();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            resolve(resp.token);
        }
        else {
            reject('some error...');
        }
    });
}
```

Now, if I would change the target in my tsconfig.json to **es5**, the compiled and bundled code (main.js) in the browser looks like this:

```
    SomeController.prototype.logIn = function (password) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var req, response, resp;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            switch (_a.label) {
                case 0:
                    req = {
                        password: password
                    };
                    return [4 /*yield*/, window.fetch("/something/login", {
                            method: 'POST',
                            // headers: headers,
                            body: JSON.stringify(req)
                        })];
                case 1:
                    response = _a.sent();
                    return [4 /*yield*/, response.json()];
                case 2:
                    resp = _a.sent();
                    return [2 /*return*/, new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                            if (response.status === 200) {
                                resolve(resp.token);
                            }
                            else {
                                reject('some error...');
                            }
                        })];
            }
        });
    });
};
```